# Perl lexer: why does "<=>" eq "=" in the context of <=><=><=>?

Tags: perl, constants, spaceship-operator

I was just reading the secret pseudo-constants, namely the *Space fleet constant*

```
<=><=><=>   Space fleet                 0
```

This seems to be because the outer `<=>` is doing something I don't understand. My question is why does

```
my $foo = <=>;
```

Set `$foo` to `=`? Other non-alphanumerics seem to work too,

```
my $foo = <=>;
my $foo = <->;
my $foo = </>;
```

But, alphanumerics don't...

```
my $foo = <a>;
```

Moreover, [the `perlsecret` pod is confusing to me](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod),

> Even though it looks like a sequence of three spaceship operators, only the middle ship is an actual spaceship. The two outer "spaceships" are actually calls to `glob("=")`.

It doesn't seem to be the case either, as I can't make sense as to why, `glob("=")` would return `=`, but `glob("a")` would return `undef` -- even if there is a file called `a` in the current working directory.

What is Perl doing in both of these cases? I assume it's falling back to a literal if the thing inside the `<>` isn't an alphanumeric -- is that behavior supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see what's going on,

```
glob("*asdf*");
```

Will return only files that have the string `asdf` in their name because the metacharacter expansion tests for file-exists. However,

```
glob("asdf");
```

will **always** return `asdf`, regardless of the status of the file. By extension `<=>` lackinging a metacharacter will also return `'='`.

Answer (score 9):

Where an expression is expected, Perl picks the first of the following that applies:

- `<>` is short for `<ARGV>`
- `<<>>` is a "safe" version of `<>` (uses 3-arg open instead of 2-arg open)
- `<<` is otherwise the start of a [here-doc operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%3c%3c_EOF_).
- `<IDENTIFIER>` is short for [`readline(IDENTIFIER)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html)
- `<...>` is otherwise short for [`glob(qq<...>)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)

Where an infix or postfix operator is expected, Perl picks the first of the following that applies:

- `<=>` is the [numerical comparison operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators).
- `<=` is otherwise the numerical less-than-or-equal operator.
- `<<` is the shift operator.
- `<` is otherwise the numerical less-than operator.

(The last three might not be relevant here. I added them to cover everything starting with `<`.)

So,

- ```
  <=><=><=>
  ```

  is short for

  ```
  glob(qq<=>) <=> glob(qq<=>)
  ```

  which can be written

  ```
  glob("=") <=> glob("=")
  ```

  or

  ```
  "=" <=> "="
  ```

  since a glob pattern with no special glob characters simply returns the pattern.

  It warns "isn't numeric" twice and evaluates to zero.
- ```
  my $foo = <=>;
  ```

  is short for

  ```
  my $foo = glob(qq<=>);
  ```

  which can be written

  ```
  my $foo = glob("=");
  ```

  or

  ```
  my $foo = "=";
  ```
- ```
  my $foo = <a>;
  ```

  is short for

  ```
  my $foo = readline(a);
  ```

  It warns "used only once: possible typo" if there are no other mentions of `*a`.

  It warns "on unopened filehandle" if you haven't previously opened `a` as a file handle.

Comment: This is the only answer that explains why `<=>` is sometimes interpreted as a uses of `glob`, and why `<a>` isn't, which is the very question asked. (It's also the only one that explains why `<<>` is interpreted as none of those.)

Answer (score 6):

When in doubt check with `-MO=Deparse`:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e '$foo = <=>'

use File::Glob ();
$foo = glob('=');
```

Spacefleet gives 0 as both operands to `<=>` are equal,

```
perl -MO=Deparse -e '$foo = <=><=><=>'

use File::Glob ();
$foo = glob('=') <=> glob('=');
```

Answer (score 5):

```
my $foo = <=>;
my $foo = <->;
my $foo = </>;
```

These are all interpreted as uses of [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html). Since there are no `*`, `?`, or `[…]` constructions in their arguments, they expand to the text passed in.

```
my $foo = <a>;
```

This is interpreted as reading one line from a file handle called `a`.

Anyways. `<=><=><=>` behaves like `glob("=") <=> glob("=")`. Since both sides evaluate to `"="`, they're equal, and the comparison returns 0.