# Switching from `>` to `<` ruins my one-liner

Tags: perl

I am filtering for lines with more than 3 items with

```
perl -ne  'print if split > 2' file.txt
```

But when I want to filter for lines with less than 3 items I can't use

```
perl -ne  'print if split < 2' file.txt
#Unterminated <> operator at -e line 1.
```

I can work around it with either of these

```
perl -ne 'print if not split > 2' file.txt
perl -ne 'print if 2 > split' file.txt
```

But I am wondering why the expression only fails for one of `<`,`>`.

Comment: You can try `perl -ne  'print if  @{[split]} < 2' file.txt`

Comment: One thing to note is that this can be fixed by calling scalar to get the length of the array generated by calling split. `print if (scalar(split) < 2)`

Comment: `perl -ne  'print if split() < 2' file.txt` seems to work too.

Comment: @Marcus What fixes it are the parenthesis, not really the `scalar`.

Comment: Should give an "ambiguous" warning, but doesn't :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a bit of digging, and looking at the comments on your post, I think I've found the answer. The parser is attempting to understand what you mean when it sees `split <`. Without parentheses on your call to split, it needs to guess how many arguments you are passing to split (It takes 0-3, see `perldoc -f split` for more information).

Because of this, it seems to assume by default that you are trying to call it with at least one argument, which looks like the start of the null filehandle `<>`. When it sees that it is incomplete, it prints the error and aborts.

This explains why the fixes commented on your post work. They all make it clear that split is to be called with no arguments, and the parser should not look for an expression, and the `<` character can then be treated as an operator.

Comment: The `<` character is one of the several extremely overloaded characters in the Perl parser, so it can frequently be confused in this manner. Other notable ones are `/` and `*` (for very different reasons!)

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51204133/589924) to see how overloaded `<` is.